# Is auto; a valid C translation unit?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Create a file `test.c`, containing the following code:

```
auto;
```

Compile it with clang 6.0: `clang -c test.c`. It will successfully generate an object file `test.o`, albeit one with no actual content (other than the object file headers). It prints a warning, but nonetheless accepts this as valid code:

```
test.c:1:1: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
auto;
^~~~
1 warning generated.
```

By contrast, gcc 4.9 refuses to compile `test.c`, generating an error:

```
test.c:1:1: error: 'auto' in file-scope empty declaration
 auto;
 ^
```

Why does clang generate a warning yet accept this translation unit as valid, while gcc generates an error and refuses to compile it? Whose behaviour is more conforming to the C standards? What is the point of allowing an auto declaration which declares nothing?

Comment: Surely, only an *error* means code is *invalid*, while a *warning* means this code is probably dangerous, not doing what you think it does, not doing anything useful, etc., yet nonetheless not technically *invalid*.

Comment: Both issue a diagnostic, so both are equally standards-conforming. (Unless it was allowed, in which case only clang would be conformant. It isn't though.)

Comment: There is even invalid code which is allowed to compile without any diagnostic (UB). If you want constraint violations (which a declaration not declaring something is) to result in errors, use `clang -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` which refuses to compile your example. But succesfully compiling with that still doesn't mean your code is valid.

Comment: @Deduplicator: As far as the standard is concerned, a failed `_Static_assert` and `#error` both only require a diagnostic (they're not different to any other form of constraint violation or syntax error).

Comment: §5.1.2.2/1: "
A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (**identified in
an implementation-defined manner**) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be
produced in other circumstances."

Comment: @mafso: Incorrect (though it's easy to miss, since section 6.10.5, which describes `#error`, doesn't mention this). Section 4 paragraph 4 says: "The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit containing a **`#error`** preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion." I don't see a similar statement for `_Static_assert`. Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: @KeithThompson: If an implementation had a limit of how many times the letter `r` may appear on a source line, and would only behave meaningfully for files where no line contained more than two, but it was able to process a contrived source file that satisfied all of the translation limits, would its inability to meaningfully process source lines containing three or more `r` characters make it non-conforming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not valid code. But the implementation is free to give it any meaning it wants after issuing a diagnostic message.

> #### 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics
>
> 1 A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
>   an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
>   contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
>   specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be
>   produced in other circumstances.9)
>   [...]

> #### 6.7 Declarations
>
> **Constraints**
>   2 A declaration other than a `static_assert` declaration shall declare at least a declarator
>   (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or
>   the members of an enumeration.
>   [...]

Quotes from C99+Amendments (C11, n1570)

Comment: You've answered my question from the standards perspective, thanks. But, what I'm still trying to understand, is **why** - why did gcc devs do one thing and clang devs another. I assume they don't just flip a coin when deciding whether something is an error or just a warning. gcc's approach seems more logical, except that inconsistently, gcc only errors for "auto;" and "register;" storage classes, while "typedef;", "extern;" and "static;" are just warnings (like clang).

Comment: @Simon The same reason why clang decides to use `-fcolor-diagnostics` and gcc `-fdiagnostics-color`. Because they felt like it. Sometimes you'll be able to find reasoning in the mailing lists or bug tracker (but that takes a bit of searching.)